# Why a variable assignment replaces tabs with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, variables

Why does a variable assignment replace tabs with spaces in the shell?

```
$ cat tmp
a    b e    c    d
$ res=$(cat tmp)
$ echo $res
a b e c d
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to quote your variable `$res` for whitespace to be preserved.

```
$ cat file
a       b e     c       d

$ res=$(cat file)

$ echo $res
a b e c d

$ echo "$res"
a       b e     c       d
```

From `man bash` under `QUOTING`:

> Quoting  is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters
>   or words to the shell.
>          Quoting can be used to  disable  special  treatment  for  special  characters,  to  prevent
>          reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent parameter expansion.
>
> Each  of the metacharacters listed above under DEFINITIONS has special meaning to the shell
>          and must be quoted if it is to represent itself.
>
> ```
> ...
>
> \a     alert (bell)
> \b     backspace
> \e
> \E     an escape character
> \f     form feed
> \n     new line
> \r     carriage return
> \t     horizontal tab
> \v     vertical tab
> \\     backslash
> \'     single quote
> \"     double quote
> \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn
> \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH
> \cx    a control-x character
>
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 7):

It isn't the assignment that's losing the tabs, but invoking the `echo` command.

`res` is assigned a value that includes tabs. When in the shell you write `$res` that's the equivalent of typing in the contents of the `res` variable at that point.

So:

```
$ echo $res
```

does the same as:

```
$ echo a    b e     c       d
```

(where the big spaces in that line are tab characters, which can be typed by pressing `Ctrl+V Tab`). And if you run that command you also get:

```
a b e c d
```

So your question actually is: why do tabs go missing in a command's arguments?

The answer is that the command (`echo` in this case) never sees the tabs, or indeed the spaces. The shell parses your command-line into a command name and a list of arguments. It uses white-space (tabs and spaces) to split the command into these parts. Then it runs the command, passing it the argument list.

So what `echo` receives as its arguments is the list ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘e’, ‘c’, ‘d’; it has no idea what characters originally separated them.

What `echo` then does is output each of its arguments, with a space between them. Hence the output you see. Where the original command line used a single space character to separate each argument the output matches the input, so it looks rather like the spaces in the input are also in the output — but they aren't: the shell gobbles up the original spaces and `echo` inserts some new ones.

Quote marks can be used to make the shell treat multiple ‘words’ as a single argument. For example if you do:

```
$ echo a    "b    c"    d
```

that is passing 3 arguments to `echo`: ‘a’, ‘b    c’, and ‘d’. The middle argument contains 4 spaces; those get passed to `echo`, so will appear in its output. The spaces outside the quote marks are used by the shell for splitting arguments, so aren't passed to `echo`. Hence the output is:

```
a b    c d
```

To check this kind of thing it's clearer to use a command which shows you exactly how many arguments it received and what was in each of them. This Perl one-liner will do that:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper \@ARGV' a    b    c    d
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c',
          'd'
        ];

$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper \@ARGV' "a    b    c    d"
$VAR1 = [
          'a    b    c    d'
        ];

$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper \@ARGV' a    "b    c"    d
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b    c',
          'd'
        ];

$ res="a    b c     d"
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper \@ARGV' $res
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c',
          'd'
        ];

$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper \@ARGV' "$res"
$VAR1 = [
          'a    b c     d'
        ];
```